# Can't rename directory by changing upper- to lower-case on hfs+ partition in Ubuntu

Tags: partition, unix, hfs+

I'm new to Linux, and just installed Ubuntu 17.04 on a dual-boot MacBook. I'm having trouble with directories I'm creating on an hfs+ partition (created with gparted, so I can see files on it when booted into OS X). I'm assuming the confusion has to do with the hfs+ format being case-insensitive, but then, shouldn't it really be case insensitive, whether I'm working on it via Ubuntu or OS X? Here's the scenario:

1. Created directory "DropBox" via Nautilus.
2. Tried to rename "DropBox" to "Dropbox" but got error message: 'The item could not be renamed. The name "Dropbox" is already in use...'.
3. Tried deleting "DropBox" (permanently, not to Trash) and creating new directory "Dropbox". When I did that, both directories appeared ("DropBox" and "Dropbox").
4. Tried deleting "DropBox", but both directories were deleted.
   Looked in Terminal; while both "DropBox" and "Dropbox" are visible in Nautilus, running `ls -a shows only "DropBox".
5. Still in Terminal, deleted "DropBox" (rm -R DropBox). As expected, this resulted in there being no dropbox folder of any sort. However, in Nautilus, I still see "Dropbox", until I try to open it, at which time I get an error that says it doesn't really exist, and then it disappears from Nautilus, too.
6. In Terminal, re-create the directory (mkdir Dropbox). The directory is recreated as "DropBox" again, and shows up as such in Nautilus as well.

Here is the mount options for the drive: `/dev/sdb2 on /data type hfsplus (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8)`

Dropbox is not yet synced to this directory, so I know it has nothing to do with Dropbox.

Is there any way around this issue, or is it unavoidable when using hfs+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around further, I found the solution to this issue. **It is actually possible to format an hfs+ partition in OS X as case-sensitive, unjournaled**, though it takes two steps. There's no way to switch an existing case-insensitive partition to case-sensitive.

The option to disable journaling (or to format a vol as case-sensitive, not journaled) has been removed from the OS X Disk Utility in El Capitan (which is the version I'm running) but it can still be done:

1. Depending on how the disk is partitioned, it might be necessary to carve out the disk space first on Linux (using `gparted` is the easiest way). I'm fairly sure it doesn't matter what type of partition, but just to be careful, I created it as hfs+ to make sure there were no weird access issues on the OS X side.
2. In OS X, use Disk Utility to format the partition as **HFS+ Case-Sensitive, Journaled**. (It should be possible to do in Terminal using `diskutil`, as well, but I didn't want to take the time to hunt down the syntax for case-sensitivity).
3. Still in OS X, in Terminal, run `diskutil disableJournal /dev/volname`. You can run this with the disk mounted or unmounted. (If you're not sure of the disk or volume name, `diskutil list` will list them all).

*Side note*: From the number of posted questions on the subject, it appears that mounting hfs+ as rw in Ubuntu is problematic for many. The syntax for designating mount of an hfs+ partition as rw in fstab (`/etc/fstab` is used by the system to mount devices at boot) is `UUID=<UUID> /mountpoint hfsplus rw,exec,auto,users 0 0`, assuming you want the typical options for a non-system data vol. If you want something different, [this article is really helpful](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab). You will also probably need to `chown -R user /mountpoint` the mountpoint.

And that's it. I tested it out back in Ubuntu, using the same "DropBox" name change test I used before, and it all looks good.

Comment: I formatted an external disk as hfs+ nonjournaled case-sensitive from a Linux host, but when I plugged it into any Mac, I got only "the disk you inserted was not readable by this computer", and a single line in `/var/log/system.log` "USBMSC identifier (non-unique)" followed by some hex strings.  Thanks for showing how to format like this from macos itself!